# OCMClassMock Exception At Runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, xcode6, ocmock

I'm currently building a test that checks if each PSColour within a criteria is a `navigationColour` (Blue, Brown). I have it set up to mock the colour and stub the method `isNavigationColour` result to be a BOOL for each colour.

I then give each of these colours an ID and put them into an array called criteria which is passed into my method `navigationColoursFromCriteria` to return and array of navigation colours.

When I run this test normally it returns an exception on the `initWithValue` method of OCMReturnValueProvider saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm new to OCMock and can't find anything wrong with my implementation but another weird thing is that the test runs successfully if I set a breakpoint at the start of the test and then go line by line to the end.

My test and relevant methods are included below:

```
- (void)testNavigationColourWithCriteria_WithColourIdArray_ShouldReturnColoursInCorrectOrder {
PSCriteria *criteria = [[PSCriteria alloc] init];

id blueColour = OCMClassMock([PSColour class]);
[[[blueColour stub] andReturnValue:@YES] isNavigationColour];
OCMStub([blueColour localizedNames]).andReturn(@{@"en" : @"Blue"});

id brownColour = OCMClassMock([PSColour class]);
[[[brownColour stub] andReturnValue:@YES] isNavigationColour];
OCMStub([brownColour localizedNames]).andReturn(@{@"en" : @"Brown"});

id blackColour = OCMClassMock([PSColour class]);
[[[blackColour stub] andReturnValue:@NO] isNavigationColour];
OCMStub([blackColour localizedNames]).andReturn(@{@"en" : @"black"});

id yellowColour = OCMClassMock([PSColour class]);
[[[yellowColour stub] andReturnValue:@NO] isNavigationColour];
OCMStub([yellowColour localizedNames]).andReturn(@{@"en" : @"yellow"});

id colourMock = OCMClassMock([PSColour class]);
OCMStub([colourMock colourWithColourId:1]).andReturn(blueColour);
OCMStub([colourMock colourWithColourId:2]).andReturn(brownColour);
OCMStub([colourMock colourWithColourId:3]).andReturn(blackColour);
OCMStub([colourMock colourWithColourId:4]).andReturn(yellowColour);

criteria.colourIds =   @[@1,@2,@3,@4];

NSArray *navigationColours = [criteria navigationColoursFromCriteria:criteria];
NSArray *result = @[@"Blue",@"Brown"];
XCTAssertEqualObjects(navigationColours, result); }


   - (NSMutableArray *)navigationColoursFromCriteria:(PSCriteria *)criteria {
```

navigationColoursFromCriteria:

```
NSMutableArray *navigationColours = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:criteria.colourIds.count];

for (NSNumber *colourId in criteria.colourIds) {
    PSColour *colour = [PSColour colourWithColourId:[colourId integerValue]];
    if (colour.isNavigationColour) {
        [navigationColours addObject:colour.localizedNames[@"en"]];
    }
}
return navigationColours; }
```

I'd appreciate any help or tips on how my test could be improved and this problem fixed.

Comment: What happens when you stub the `isNavigationColour` method using the modern syntax, ie. `OCMStub([blue color isNavigationColour]).andReturn(YES)`?

Comment: No luck, forgot to mention I'm using OCMock 2 by the way. It turns out that you can't return a dictionary directly to the OCMStub so I saved each localizedName as a variable and passed that in instead and all my tests passed.